# Postfix sending mails successfully but receivers don't get them

Tags: php, email, smtp, xenforo, postfix-mta

I've tried using Postfix only as a SMTP server for sending "verification" mails locally, to any provided destination. The current problem is, it sends all mails without any issues but receivers don't get them.

I'm using XenForo software with "127.0.0.1:25" SMTP data for sending mails, without user - / pass login because Postfix is locally bound and should **only send** mails - **not** receiving any from outside.

Also I'm using my custom domain to provide "from:" data for mail. (e.g. "no-reply@*******.com")

I already tried using SMTP servers of different hosts such as "MailJet" but I had the same issue there. The staff of used hosts said, there'd be something wrong with my server and nothing else, so that's why I had decided to host an own SMTP server locally on the same server as like as my webserver's running.

---

Postfix "main.cf" file: http://pastebin.com/r8EfKbXL

Logs: http://pastebin.com/TnjVbNfp

---

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,

Chris

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because email deliverability questions are explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you have SPF, DKIM, etc. all sorted? I suggest you (authenticate with and) use the same SMTP server you use for all other email from that domain, create a separate inbox if you need so it's using different credentials to you. It's usually a lot less hassle.